# Database is locked when inside a foreach with linq without ToList()

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've tried looking for an answer but couldn't find it. The 'issue' is simple:

If I have a collection of items using linq as follows:

```
var items = db.AnyTable.Where(x => x.Condition == condition).ToList();
```

And another collection of items using linq but without a `ToList()`:

```
var items2 = db.AnyTable.Where(x => x.Condition == condition);
```

If now I try to iterate each item with a foreach (I didn't try `while` or other kind of iteration methods):

```
foreach (var item in items) 
{
    int i = 2;// Doesn't matter, The important part is to put a breakpoint here.
}
```

If I stop the code at the breakpoint and I try to update the `AnyTable` on SQL Management Studio everything is OK. BUT IF!:

```
foreach (var item in items2) 
{
    int i = 2;// Doesn't matter, The important part is to put a breakpoint here.
}
```

If now I try to update (while on the breakpoint) the `AnyTable` on SQL Management Studio I won't be able to do it (TimeOut).

Why is the `ToList()` making such a difference?

From what I've learnt a particular difference is WHEN the query is being executed (on `items` it is executed at the declaration and on `items2` it is executed on the `foreach` statement). Why is that preventing me to update the `AnyTable` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linq query is only translated to SQL query when you access the data.
When you call ToList() you create a SQL query that returns all the data to the code from the db. Now the items var is entirely in memory and no more work is done against the db. 
In the second example, you are using foreach, which opens a trnasaction in the db,
and while this transaction is still open, you are trying to change the data
you will get the timeout, since the table is held by the open LINQ query against the DB.

Comment: So the `foreach` statement creates a Transaction? wow. Any way to prevent that? (and what kind of transaction creates? `Serializable` ?

Comment: Yes , i believe that is the case. In a simple test I made , I had no problem inserting from SSMS while the foreach iteration was on a breakpoint. You can use sql profiler to see exactly why the query gets locked

Answer (score 0):

ToList() forces execution of the full query.

However if you enumerate without ToList() then it will query as needed.